# I keep getting [Object Object] when trying to access parsed JSONP from JSONP

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I'm trying to grab some JSONP to make a podcast episode media player, and parsing the JSONP seems successful (the success alert goes off, and the object shows up in Chrome developer tools), but I cannot figure out how to access the object. When I do in the way below, I just get "[object,object]"  I want to start putting the information from the JSONP file into the body of the HTML document. Thanks!

```
 function getProfile() {

$.jsonp({
  "url": "foo.com&callback=?",
  "data": {
      "alt": "json-in-script"
  },
  "success": function(data) {
  alert("working!");
  document.write(data);
  },
  "error": function() {
      alert("no luck!");
  }
});
}
```

Comment: `data` is an object. What did you want instead?

Comment: what framework? sample data? caled url? anything?

Answer (score 1):

The document.write function doesn't have the ability to write a JavaScript object onto the page, it will just print the [object,object] you see.

If you try console.log(data) instead you will be able to use the chrome console to see your JavaScript object, once you know the structure you can start manipulating it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do you manipulate it? Every way I try  returns "undefined."

Comment: um without knowing the structure, could you supply the json and then I could help more?